# reply to thread by email

Tags: php, email, wave, inbox

I have a threaded inbox  . By threaded I mean  , just like this question is a thread , all replies are aggregated below it .

I want to add this functionality :

let's say , I started a thread . Now 10 people got notification by email that thread is started.

if user1 replies to this email , the reply should become part of thread on the website . 
if user2 replies to this email , the reply should come next to reply of user 1 .

---

Example :

Basecamp does this .

for example , if my username on basecamp is stackoverflow.com

I create a task1 , an email is sent with REPLY-TO address : 
U3767129P22197427-reply@stackoverflow.projectpath.com

if I reply to this address , my reply is automatically added to basecamp/projectpath website .

Do I have to create a new email address for every thread ?

Comment: Umm, that's up to you?  Why do you want all these strange reply-to addresses?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't, you would need to configure a catch-all address with your hosting provider, which will take all email and forward it to a specific inbox.  Then you just have to have php read through the email in that inbox and match the TO address with the information in your database.

Another way is to encode the subject line with something like DX-CODEGOESHERE- [DO NOT MODIFY]